# Colors inside DIN 5 (MIDI) cable

Tags: connector, cables, colour-coding

Today about my first components in an electronic store. I'm currently making a MIDI IN circuit for my Raspberry PI.

My local shop didn't have male to male DIN 5 pin cables, as they seem to be obsolete, just like MIDI, and thought I'd buy a male to female cable, and cut the female connection and connect the needed cables to my breadboard manually.

This seems like a good plan, except for the fact that I have no clue which color represents which pin on the DIN 5 cable, and the Internet, for once, has given me no answer until now.

I need to find pins 4 and 5 in the cable.

I currently have

- Blue
- Green
- Black (possibly pin 2)
- White
- Reddish

If needed I can attach a photograph, but there really isn't much more to it than this.

Which pin is represented by which color?

**EDIT:** Currently checking for continuity manually with a multimeter.

Comment: I really in doubt there is a definitive standard for this. Grab a multimeter and check the continuity.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Let's hope this works. There is really no reason it wouldn't work, but being a practical layman is definitely not a pro.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Checking for continuity worked after all. Post an answer if you wish and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: What kind of cable did you buy? It's possible that it is not properly shielded, or that the shield is not connected to pin 2.

Comment: @CL. It was a male to female DIN 5 cable, not really sure whether it was shielded or not.

Comment: If it was not called a "MIDI cable", then it does not have the shield connected to pin 2. (And a MIDI cable would have only two wires.) But it's likely to work anyway.

Comment: @CL.I asked for DIN 5 cable, and the guy at the shop asked something like what polarization I wanted it, I was dumbstruck, and he asked me if it was for MIDI, to which I could respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made on my Arduino Uno some MIDI in/outs, but never seen some color scheme.

The MIDI ports have specific numbers (which are not so intuitive). And also check good what is the front and back.

Btw, MIDI is far from obsolete. Every synth still uses them (although USB MIDI is getting more popular, a lot of music devices with with DIN5 MIDI plugs). MIDI cables can be found at every decent music shop.